# Tree shaking not working - webpack 4 and uglifyjs-webpack-plugin

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs, tree-shaking

I have tried adding UglifyJSPlugin to a webpack 4 project, in accordance with the webpack docs, and I'm still seeing dead code and even comments in my bundle which leads me to think that my uglify plugin config isn't being used.

[Link to project](https://github.com/gpspake/es6-todomvc)

The [docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#conclusion) state that "in order to take advantage of tree shaking, you must...
- Use ES2015 module syntax (i.e. import and export). [done](https://github.com/gpspake/es6-todomvc/blob/master/src/helpers.js#L1)
- Add a "sideEffects" entry to your project's package.json file. [done](https://github.com/gpspake/es6-todomvc/blob/master/package.json#L38) .
- Include a minifier that supports dead code removal (e.g. the UglifyJSPlugin)." [done](https://github.com/gpspake/es6-todomvc/blob/master/webpack.config.babel.js#L39)

Still, the unused/unimported leftpad function and comments are being included in my bundle.

All of the config can be seen [here](https://github.com/gpspake/es6-todomvc).
Based on the results I'm seeing, I suspect that this is related to the [uglify settings](https://github.com/gpspake/es6-todomvc/blob/master/webpack.config.babel.js#L39) in my webpack config.

To reproduce, pull the [repo](https://github.com/gpspake/es6-todomvc) and run `yarn build`

Comment: Stuck....Where you able to fix this ?

Comment: What's the output of `webpack --verbose [...other opts]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **tree shaking is only enabled in production mode**

See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6992#issuecomment-379665061

[This explanation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) is misleading, because not only UglifyJsPlugin but also a bunch of plugins are needed to make it work as explained [here](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/#usage).

I have not tried enabling all the plugins to see if it works. I have tried "--optimize-minimize" option but it doesn't work.